# What is the difference "each" or "each one" or "each of them"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference "**each**" or "**each one**" or "**each of them**" or "**each one of them**"?

For example:

> "Cells can be classified into two main groups: prokaryotic and
>   eukaryotic. Each (or each one) can be classified farther into
>   sub-classifications.

As you can see I have 4 choices and I don't really know the differences between them:

1) **Each** can be classified farther into sub-classifications.

2) **Each one** can be classified farther into sub-classifications.

3) **Each of them** can be classified farther into sub-classifications.

4) **Each one of them** can be classified farther into sub-classifications.

Answer (score 4):

They are equivalent; "each..." refers to "every one of two or more people or things, regarded and identified separately". To add as "Each [one] [of them]" etc is redundant and merely serves to embellish.

Comment: I agree with this but would add: Each one of them might be  used in other contexts for emphasis purposes...

Comment: Yes, one can provide emphasis by accumulation: Each one of them will die - each single, last, living, breathing, mother-loving man-jack of them will die!

Comment: Are you sure that "Each can be classified..." (variant 1) is a correct wording? I'm not a native speaker, but it sounds very unusual to me.

Comment: It is correct. 'Each' can stand alone. The children were dressed in patriotic costumes; each carried a flag.